# Sequence Generator

Tags: c#, database, sequence

I got a DB which store customer details(I have a Form to enter details and customer number is generated automatically).If I have 1,2,3,4,5 as customer IDs then next time when I create a customer the Form should default Customer ID as 6.

I achieved the Above Goal.But the Thing is if I simultaneously create two customers both will show up as 6.But What I want every Time open a Form the value of Customer ID should be unique.(i.e) If I click create customer Now it should show 6 and after that i open another form simultaneously i should get customer ID as 7 ...

How to achieve this?

Comment: First add your item then fetch its ID. If user cancel the form just remove it. Otherwise...do not show any ID while adding a new customer. What's all that stuff about ID for? usually your database can generate it for you (if you're not using a databse consider using generated GUID or a data layer).

Comment: Can't you deal with that as `IDENTITY` columns at database layer?

Comment: Why not have this functionality in the DB? In mySQL you can set your ID field to autoincrement, in MSSQL you can set your ID field as an identity column, in Oracle you can use a sequence to generate the ID, etc.

Comment: Why not using GUID's? They are commonly used for Unique ID's and they prevent security holes because their ID's are not predictable. You can create a GUID in C# with 1 line of code: `var guid = Guid.NewGuid();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to make **Customer ID** as primary key with auto increment.

So whenever you add the values into customer table, Id will be Unique and it will be incremented automatically.

Reason Behind this is : In your code if two users are using the same form at a time, both will receive the same **maxPartyId** and when both users submit the form, the same Id **maxPartyId + 1** will be stored. That means customer id will be duplicate in your database

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- **Database**: Let your DBMS do the primary key generation for you; don't assume you have a valid ID until you finish record generation. Implementation will heavily depend on your database of choice.
- **Singleton/mutual-exclusion lock**: Let a single class generate and distribute IDs. Use the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to prevent parallel generation.

Personally I would recommend the first approach; Implementation is usually cleaner, and you don't have to bother about thread locking.